# Right click or two finger tap

Tags: macos, right-click

How do I add the CTRL+W or Close Window, Close Tab otion to the right click or double tap menus?

Comment: Thomas, you're going to have to add a bit more detail than that in order to get a good answer.

Comment: What close-window option? What contextual menu? In which application? Why can't you just press cmd+w? Make it easier to answer your question..

Answer (score 1):

It's gonna be in the option of your touchpad... But you didn't give enought details on what u are using actually so it's hard to guide you at the right place...

Please Edit your message and add informations...

And also, this is not really the good place to ask for it.

Answer (score 1):

This actually is programming related (though I'm not sure whether the asker meant it to be). You need to write a [contextual menu plugin](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/DisplayContextMenu.html).

Comment: @Chuck-I'm curious, how can you assume that they are referring to a app menu on a Mac, oppose to a web browser or anything else?

Comment: He tagged it "Mac" and asked about adding items to contextual menus (which are called up on a Mac either by right-clicking or two-finger clicking on a trackpad). It seemed like a reasonable interpretation to me.

Comment: duh...my eyes missed that tag